# Does RetroArch have a PAL filter like the NTSC one?

Tags: emulation, nes, ntsc, pal

RetroArch the emulator "wrapper" has an option to enable an NTSC filter over the image, simulating the visual look of a composite NTSC signal/TV. Here is a comparison between the "raw" (no filter) mode and with the filter turned on:

[image]

[image]

Note how it's *not* some simple "blurring" or "anti-aliasing" filter.

Although I'm not exactly sure how different NTSC and PAL look, I'm bothered by the fact that it says "NTSC" and not "PAL". I'm sure that there are some differences in the look between an NTSC and PAL TV/signal. If somebody made a filter/"shader" for NTSC, it seems like a minor addition (for the ones who know this stuff) to make a PAL one as well. I've looked all over the options/menus without finding any mention of PAL except for the aspect ratio.

So I'm forced to emulate my PAL games with the NTSC composite filter and "pretend" to myself that it's a PAL filter, but deep down, I know it's NTSC, and it bothers me a lot.

Comment: It's actually not a minor addition - if you want to emulate all the oddities, PAL is quite a bit different from NTSC. Also, probably even the NTSC filter only gets the most basic things right. Having proper filters to simulate NTSC and PAL TV artifacts is something I've been wanting for a long time.

Comment: Retroarch does not have a PAL filter. But it does have PAL shaders: https://github.com/libretro/common-shaders/tree/master/pal. And yes, PAL is not NTSC, it looks quite different!

Comment: Just doing PAL/NTSC color bleed is not enough. To fully emulate a retro system it should do any video noise specific to the platform, plus CRT shadow mask, convergence errors and pincushion distortion! All the stuff we _didn't_ want when we had it!